# javascript - Cannot read property "cart" of undefined which is a session attribute

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, session

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var Cart = require('../models/cart')

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  var cart = new Cart(req.session.cart)
});
```

When I execute the above node.js program using "get" method,
the following error is triggered.

> Cannot read property 'cart' of undefined
>
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'cart' of undefined

I would like to simulate a shopping cart and use a session attribute to store the record when users try to add items into cart.

This program is to read a session attribute "cart", no matter it is created or not, to return the active session's cart record.

However, it seems the program cannot recognize this "cart" session attribute if I have not initialized it before.

How can I resolve this issue such that the program will not return error?

Comment: `req` doesn't have property `session` according to the error.

Comment: you are doing a get call to the api how come are you passing an object to it. provide the code with which you are executing this call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to access a `session` property which does not exist on `req`, because you are not using any session middleware.

Even if you create such a property, it will not persist across HTTP requests, you need to use a session manager to handle that persistence.

You can use the basic [express-session](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session).

```
// require it
var session = require('express-session')

// configure it
app.use(session({
    secret: '123456',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    cookie: {
        secure: true
    }
}))
```

Then all your requests will have a `session` property.